# Canonical dupes regarding C loop ordering and cache performance

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

We have two highly up-voted canonical duplicates for "loop ordering and cache performace" in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

- [Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra)
- [Which ordering of nested loops for iterating over a 2D array is more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888154/which-ordering-of-nested-loops-for-iterating-over-a-2d-array-is-more-efficient)

The former was closed as a dupe of the latter, but since I believed the former had better answers, I single handedly dupe un-hammered it, couple of years ago.

I don't think we need 2 posts, but given how many votes these posts have, I don't think I alone should make the call to dupe hammer.

Proposal:

- Keep
  [Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra)
- Close as dupe: [Which ordering of nested loops for iterating over a 2D array is more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888154/which-ordering-of-nested-loops-for-iterating-over-a-2d-array-is-more-efficient)

If you agree/disagree, up/down-vote this question as usual.

I personally don't think the "which ordering" question/answers need preserving. But if a mod would be willing to merge them, that's another option. The questions are almost completely identical, they just wrote the order of the `i` and `j` iterators differently. Some manual tweaking of which example that is the first/second might be needed upon merging.

Comment: How would removing that question improve the site? To me it seems that keeping it just makes it easier for people to find that information.

Comment: @JoeW OP proposes to close one as a duplicate or merge them, they don't propose to remove one of the questions.

Comment: @JoeW Generally, we don't need to have the same question posted over and over, which is why we have the duplicate close reason. Specifically, this is about picking a "canonical dupe" which we can use to close new questions asking this yet again. That should be the best question with the best answers.

Comment: Notably, the one I propose to keep was already closed in year 2012 before I re-opened it in 2016. So we didn't use to have both these questions open.

Comment: Look at their view counts for to see that they are not equivalent.  Having more than six times as many views is nothing to sneeze at, you'd have to identify the magic that made that happen to make the right call.  Well, don't keep the one with the low view count.

Comment: @Stijn The last part of the question talks about one of them not needing to be preserved and maybe merging both questions which is why I made that comment. I do find it interesting that the one he proposes using as a dupe target already has a edit saying it might be a dupe of the other one.

Comment: @HansPassant Vote/view count isn't necessarily a reliable metric. It might be that one ended up higher ranked in some search engine. Or that one is simply older (in this case they are both about as old). Only technical/pedagogic quality should matter.

Comment: The overall appeal of the former Q&A just seems better in terms of being explicit with its explanations. For example, the top voted answer is much more suitable for a canonical as most details and subtleties are adressed. I personally don't think merging is necessary. I would agree with you that closing the latter as dupe sounds like the best decision here.

Comment: Has anyone every given any thought to grouping dups, rather than just closing all but one?  Often times, I'll find a Q closed as a dup, but the answers are better than the one the dup points to.  I worry that there are other Q&As, closed as dups, that have more (and useful) information.  Perhaps, when something gets closed as a dup, all the dups could be put into a _"dup bucket"_ that every question could point to.  When you traversed the link, you could see all the Q&As, perhaps each having a community score saying which of the many had the best info.

Comment: @Flydog57 hit Meta with the Feature-Request (disclaimer: haven't checked for dupes of that oops) ? :)

Comment: @Flydog57 That's basically the "Linked" questions in the sidebar. Those are all of the questions in the "dupe bucket". Moderators can also merge answers from one question into the master question, but we do this sparingly, because it doesn't make sense unless the two questions are *exactly* the same. If you want us to merge, raise a custom moderator flag and give evidence you've considered the implications of a merge.

Comment: @Flydog57 It's mainly because of over-zealous close-voting. An older post is not necessarily the best post. Sometimes it is worth to let a question simmer for a day or so, there might be better answers popping up than what the dupe contained. Then the old post can be closed as a dupe to the new one.

Comment: The top-rated and accepted answer in the second question ("Which ordering...") doesn't even mention the word cache, or even really explain why one is better than the other.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think that's a good approach. If people have better answers than the existing ones on an old post they can just post the answers there. There's the problem of those questions not get bumped on top of newest list, but we can make a FR about "refreshing" questions when a new closed as duplicated question has some high score.

Comment: @CodyGray: The Linked sidebar accumulates *all* questions linked in any answers or comments, and all posts that have any links back to *this* question.  I (and some other people) put links into answers for tangential reasons, or for background knowledge that I want to build on without explaining over again.  This basically pollutes the Linked lists of some canonical or otherwise frequently-linked questions, meaning we don't have a list of just highly-related questions for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per community consensus, 22 for 3 against 2019-03-08:

- Closed as duplicate: [Which ordering of nested loops for iterating over a 2D array is more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888154/which-ordering-of-nested-loops-for-iterating-over-a-2d-array-is-more-efficient)
- Canonical post: [Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra)

The latter has been cleaned up and the [SO C wiki FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) points at it.