# Why is this considered a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

[Know if the context menu is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018521/know-if-the-context-menu-is-opened)

So this question asks about knowing if the context menu is open in javascript. While it closed with duplicate, two questions were linked. However, after reading the titles of the question, I wouldn't imagine that the user would even have found the answer. The titles are different, while one is quite vague.

[Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Quite Vague. How would the user know to search this? Especially since they are looking for the context menu. In which, there is a context menu key on most windows keyboards? The question seems more for a mouse event or a click event, rather than a context menu event.

[How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)

Again, how would the user know to call a context menu a right-click menu? I for sure would not call this a right-click menu. Plus, the user doesn't seem concerned with creating a custom menu, just the event to know when it's open. So the title doesn't provide the user value, even if the user was able to find it.

So I really don't see this question as a duplicate. Just other questions with different goals, with similar solutions. The poor question even had a downvote. I don't see it as a bad question and honestly, the title is worded better.

As a side note, I don't even know how I ended up on this question. I didn't even search context-menu or right-click. Just after reading it, seeing the [duplicate] tag, it just didn't make sense.

Comment: The only relevant question is: Do these two linked questions answer the question?

Comment: "How would the user know to search this?" They wouldn't. That's why it's marked as a duplicate. So the next person who searches for "context menu" gets the answer immediately. The OP of the duplicate question gets their answer. Users searching for similar keywords get their answers. All in one place. Win win win.

Comment: A difference in terminology doesn't make it any less of a duplicate.

Comment: I imagine this stems from a misunderstanding of what marking a question as a duplicate does. Asking a duplicate question is not necessarily a bad thing, and closing as a duplicate is a positive action, not a negative one. Duplicates that ask the same thing in very different ways act as wonderful [signposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/363946) so that answers can be found with different search terms and aren't hidden in different questions. Of course, there can be [too many signposts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386212/7795130), and that's when duplicates start to get a bad rap.

Answer (score 12):

The fact the asker didn't know how to find the duplicates do not make the question not a duplicate.

On the other hand, it makes very clear the usefulness of the duplicate system: helping users to find existing answers they wouldn't have found by themselves.

The signposts are there not only for the question author, but for any other users that use a similar terminology than them.

Now, thanks to the question being closed as a dupe, users searching by similar keywords than this user will find the answers they need without having to ask the question again.